# Using a bitwise AND on more than two bits

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit, bitwise-operators

I am pretty new to bitwise operators. Let's say I have 3 variables `a`, `b` and `c`, with these values in binary:

```
  a = 0001
  b = 0011
  c = 1011
```

Now, I want to perform a bitwise AND like this:

```
    a
AND b
AND c
--------
d = 0001
```

`d &= a &= b &= c` doesn't work (as I expected), but how can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What's wrong with just this.

```
d = a & b & c;
```

Comment: Oh damn ofcourse. I forgot I can use them without an `=`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You want:

```
d = a & b & c;
```

`&=` means bitwise AND and also assign.

If `d` was originally assinged to be `0` your expression as you put it would always evaluate to 0 because anything `&` `0` will equal `0`.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
int a = 1;  // 0001
int b = 3;  // 0011
int c = 11; // 1011
int d = 0;

d = a & b & c;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just forgot to initialize 'd' to being all 1's, and it defaulted to 0. You can easily set all the bits to 1 by assigning d=-1, or if you prefer, d=0xffffffff, although since you were only using 4 bits, d=0xF would have sufficed.

That being said, daisy-chaining operators like that tends to be less readable than breaking things out as others have suggested.